# Difference between 2 timestamps(String) in hours in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activesupport

I have one time in a hash as

```
"Time": "2022-11-08T22:59:00Z"
```

and also i would be taking the current time in the same format using

```
Time.now.utc.iso8601
```

I want to compare these 2 times(Time-CurrentTime) to get their difference in hours. I cant quite figure out how to do that as i am new to ruby and rails. Please help me out.

ruby 2.7.5p203

Rails 4.2.11

I tried parsing them using strftime() but maybe i was doing it wrong. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to compare `Time` object not strings. You can parse a time string using this method [`Time.parse`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_6_3/Time/parse/class). The difference will be in seconds that's why you need to divide the result by 3600

```rb
your_hash = { "Time": "2022-11-08T22:59:00Z" } 
(Time.now.utc - Time.parse(your_hash[:"Time"])) / 3600
```

Comment: This is a bit pedantic, but you can write `:Time` instead of `:"Time"`

Comment: That's true, but since @Priyanshu0007 is new to Ruby let's keep it

Comment: `"Time".to_sym ` I think it's ok

Comment: Note this is pure Ruby; not ActiveSupport/Rails.